# substitute in a nested list (prolog)

Tags: prolog

/* substitute(X,Y,Xs,Ys) is true if the list Ys is the result of substituting Y for all occurrences of X in the list Xs.

This is what I have so far:

```
subs(_,_,[],[]).
subs(X,Y,[X|L1],[Y|L2]):- subs(X,Y,L1,L2).
subs(X,Y,[H|L1],[H|L2]):- X\=H, not(H=[_|_]), subs(X,Y,L1,L2).
subs(X,Y,[H|_],[L2]):- X\=H, H=[_|_], subs(X,Y,H,L2).
```

My code works except it omits the elements following the nested list. For example:

```
?- subs(a,b,[a,[a,c],a],Z).
Z = [b, [b, c]] .
```

What should I add to this program?

Comment: This turns out to be homework: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yilan/324f09/324f09a4.pdf Next time, **please** tag it as such!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once you find a nested list, you forget about whatever is *behind* that nested list. Instead, after recursing with the nested nest, simply continue as before. Thus, you should change the last clause as follows:

```
subs(X,Y,[H|L1],[H2|L2]):- X\=H, H=[_|_], subs(X,Y,H,H2), subs(X, Y, L1, L2).
```

*Aside from that*, there are a couple of ways in which you can improve the code:

1. Use [cuts](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=!%2F0) (`!/0`) to stop backtracking. In this way you don't have to repeat yourself.
2. You can use [`is_list/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is_list%2F1) to test whether an argument is a list.
3. It's okay to use more spaces. Really.

So, an alternative solution is (now using [`\+/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B%2F1) instead of [`not/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1)):

```
subs(_, _, [], []).
subs(X, Y, [X|T1], [Y|T2]) :- subs(X, Y, T1, T2), !.
subs(X, Y, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :- \+ is_list(H), subs(X, Y, T1, T2), !.
subs(X, Y, [H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :- subs(X, Y, H1, H2), subs(X, Y, T1, T2).
```

Demonstration:

```
?- subs(a, b, [a, [a, [d, f, a]], a, b, a, [g]], Z).
Z = [b, [b, [d, f, b]], b, b, b, [g]].
```

Comment: Cuts are ugly, they hide the implicit negation in the following clauses. I find it better to use (... -> ... ; ...), which resembles if-then-else in functional programming.

Comment: @starblue: yeah, I vaguely remember there being issues with cut (only recently I regained interest in Prolog). I'll read up on it in the near future. Thanks for the heads up, and I'll upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could write it using (... -> ... ; ...):

```
subs(_, _, [], []).
subs(X, Y, [H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    (H1 == X ->
        H2 = Y
    ; is_list(H1) ->
        subs(X, Y, H1, H2),
        subs(X, Y, T1, T2)
    ;
        H1 = H2,
        subs(X, Y, T1, T2)
    ).
```